# Vue3 mutually exclusive props

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

Creating a component that accepts either `json` with `jsonParserRules` or `jsonUrl` with `jsonParserRulesUrl`, but not both. What is the correct way to achieve this. It would be perfect if the IDE will support this check and print appropriate warning in case both props specified.

**Non working example**

```
<script setup lang="ts">
type Props = |
{
  json: Object
  jsonParserRules: Object
  jsonUrl?: never
  jsonParserRulesUrl?: never
}
|{
  json?: never
  jsonParserRules?: never
  jsonUrl: string
  jsonParserRulesUrl: string
}

defineProps<Props>()
</script>

<template>
  <pre>some output</pre>
</template>
```

This straight forward attempt prints error: `[@vue/compiler-sfc] type argument passed to defineProps() must be a literal type, or a reference to an interface or literal type.`

Comment: Can you create a codepen for this?

Comment: or a https://sfc.vuejs.org/

Comment: Or a codesandbox/link a public github repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a perfect solution because you have to put both props into one but it will give you the correct typing errors in VSCode.

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
type Json = {
  json: Object;
  jsonParserRules: Object;
};
type JsonUrl = {
  jsonUrl: string;
  jsonParserRulesUrl: string;
};
type Props = {
  jsonData: Json | JsonUrl;
};
const props = defineProps<Props>();
</script>
```

Does not give VScode typescript error:

```html
<TestCompo :json-data="{ jsonUrl: 'foo', jsonParserRulesUrl: 'foo' }" />
```

Gives VScode typescript error:

```html
<TestCompo :json-data="{ jsonUrl: 'foo', jsonParserRules: {} }" />
```